# PHP/JS - Insert PHP variable containing index delivered by JS

Tags: javascript, php

I'm currently returning a PHP array to my code using the following codeline:

```
$feedback = $database->getAllFeedbacks();
```

This array would store multiple elements. Now I'm trying to add those to a pagination JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.twbs-flat').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: <?php echo $count; ?>,
        visiblePages: 4,
        prev: 'Prev',
        first: null,
        last: null,
        onPageClick: function (event, page) 
        {
            $('.twbs-content-default').text("Username: " + page);
        }
    });
</script>
```

This code works fine and adds the current site to a div. But It wouldn't work if I try to add values from the array to the following codeline:

```
$('.twbs-content-default').text("Username: " + page);
```

What I've tried so far:

```
$('.twbs-content-default').text("Username: <?php echo $feedback[" + page + "]['username']; ?>");
```

Which way could I add a PHP array index variable to the javascript function using the index of the Javascript `page` value?

Comment: Your PHP syntax is incorrect

Comment: Where is it wrong? Makes sense to me to use the . delimiter but it's confusing me since JS uses +

Comment: lol, you need to understand the execution order of your code. server side goes first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First JSON encode the array in PHP and assign it to a variable:

```
var feedbackJSON = <?php echo json_encode($feedback); ?>;
```

Then in javascript:

```
var feedbackArr = JSON.parse(feedbackJSON);
```

Then use:

```
 $('.twbs-content-default').text("Username:" + feedbackArr[page])
```

Make sure the page variable is assigned similar to this if coming from php:

```
var page = <?php echo $count; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not possible!

The php code will be execute server side and JavaScript is client side. So the page variable dosen't exist, when the php code will be execute.

**Update**

You can access the data with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "username.php?page=" + page,
  success: function(username){
    $('.twbs-content-default').text("Username: " + username);
}});
```

Comment: So I would have to create a extra PHP file which returns the array and use ajax to use the array in js then?

Comment: Yes, I think thats the best way! :)